# WebWorker behaves slower in Firefox compared to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, web-worker

Subject. I have an application, where I spawn a single WebWorker and use it to unzip files in memory. I "postMessage" a single message per file I need, in WebWorker I access the in-memory archive and unzip file and return with postMessage the "Uint8Array" object back to main thread.

In Chrome it works ok: the files come to main thread as soon as they are extracted from zip. But in FireFox there is a 30 second delay, the same delay I had before I rewrote application to use WebWorker. It feels like FireFox has some kind of queue and returns results to main thread only after this queue is empty.

I suspect that such queue could be a queue of incoming postMessages from main thread to WebWorker, but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to overcome this issue in Firefox?

## UPDATE

I made a logger of sent and received messages for postMessage in WebWorker and received message in onMessage.

And this is what I got:

Chrome: http://pastebin.com/7TUKwKZc

Firefox: http://pastebin.com/bSZ0yu33

So basically FireFox is using sync model for messaging with WebWorker thread, while Chrome is using asycn model.

Does somebody know how turn on async'ness for WebWorker threads in FireFox with JS?

Comment: Can you post some code that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: A 30 second delay smells like garbage collection.

Comment: Updated original question